# How can I fix the handling of clickable HTTP links?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, http

I am running Windows 7 RTM and have a problem with clickable links in Outlook.  I suspect it's a generic problem handling http links from the OS.  Directly within IE or other browsers, I can work fine.  It's just these links from external apps that break.  Whenever I click on a link, I get an error messagebox like so:

[image]

How can I fix up my system so that http links are correctly handled?  I'd prefer to use my default browser, but I'd be willing to settle for IE here.

---

After Neito's suggestion, I made IE the default handler for http.  Then I went back into Chrome, and Chrome told me that it was no longer the default browser.  I then made Chrome the default browser again, and now everything works happily.  http links from Outlook and other apps correctly launch inside Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens a lot if you don't have a default browser set up. I don't know 7 that well, but I know in XP there's something like "Set Program Access and Defaults". Is there something like that in 7?

Additionally, there may be an option in Outlook that you have to set to get it to open in a browser.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I did this, but Chrome (which is my default browser) didn't even show up in the programs list.  Instead I just made IE the handler for http/https, and all is well.  Now to figure out why Chrome is not in that list...

Comment: Is there a "Browse..." option? If so, you could just find chrome.exe.

Comment: Naw.  No browse option or any sort of context menu that I could see.  Not from this dialog, at least.

Comment: Do you have a "Custom" section where you can select "Use my current Web browser"?